# Android Open Fragment from Activity No view found for id 0x7f0 (com.pakagename:id/flLoginMainLayout) for fragment OpenFragmentName{ AnotherFragment}

Tags: android, android-fragments

Login Activity

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.flLoginMainLayout, 
OpenFragmentName, AppConstants.tag_prev_list_fragment);
```

it gives me error following error

E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f0113 (com.doctorstay:id/flLoginMainLayout) for fragment OpenFragmentName{4450afc0 #1 id=0x7f0f0113 AnotherFragment}

i also call same code in AnotherFragment with diff container id

```
 ((AnotherFragment) fragment).addFragment(R.id.flMainLayout,
                                OpenFragmentName, AppConstants.tag_prev_list_fragment);
```

XML Layout : activity_login_fragment (use is flLoginMainLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/flLoginMainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pakagename.pakagename2.OpenFragmentName">

</FrameLayout>
```

XML For Login Layout : activity_login (use is flLoginMainLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/flRootLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pakagename.LoginActivity">
```

Comment: Please post your layout code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue is with the view that u have use to inflate fragment**

Make sure that view is specified in the correct layout

- This exception can also happen if the layout ID which you are passing
  to FragmentTransaction.replace(int ID, fragment) exists in other
  layouts that are being inflated. Make sure the layout ID is unique
  and it should work.